# Save items from array on mysql with php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i have one situation and i dont know what exactly i need to do.

This is a multiple file upload so im doing this

```
$files = $_POST["files-temp"];
```

this return ( iten1.jpg;iten2.jpg;iten3.jpg;) there is a semicolon on last iten

then i did

```
$array = preg_split('/;/',$files);
```

then i got

```
Array ( [0] => iten1.jpg [1] => iten2.jpg [2] => iten3.jpg [3] => )
```

So there is a iten 4 that not exists, so i need to find a better way to do this then count and execut  the query to save on mysql.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$files` contains a string and want to remove that last extra array location:

Try:

```
$files = 'iten1.jpg;iten2.jpg;iten3.jpg;';
$result = explode(";", rtrim($files,';'));
print_r( $result );
```

[Test Here](http://codepad.org/YMbMtmRe)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If it is working for you, you can accept this answer.

Comment: by the away the best method now for save on mysql is usign foreach, like foreach( $result as $key => $val )
{ $query=......}